# Relation between two series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series, geometric-progressions

Consider the two series ,

A=Σ(2ⁿ/n!) from 1 to ∞.

and,

B=Σ(4ⁿ/n!) from 1 to ∞.

What is the relationship between them?( If any)

I think the exponential series might come in handy but the numerator is progressing geometrically.

I don't think squaring the series will help either since there are infinite terms.

I tried to form 2ⁿ somehow in the series B but couldn't do it since now the powers progressed in squares of 2.

Is there any way of finding  a relation between the two? Or evaluating each series by anyway?

Comment: $$\frac{B}{A}=e^2+1.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that,
$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
Hence,
$$A = e^2-1$$
$$B = e^4-1$$
Now, you can see relation between the given series.

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Both series converge according to the Ratio Test.
When you check $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}$,  you get $\frac {4}{n+1}$ and  $\frac {2}{n+1}$ where both go to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.